# 2D – 3D points matching, pose estimation and correspondance

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matching

I obtained some 2D points, x and y coordinates, from image, and I have some 3D points, x, y and z coordinates. I have to do matching between these points. My goal is to find  tha some features, same correspondances between these two groups, in this way I have to build a match matrix. Than This match matrix will be my input for EPnP solver. Someone can help me to do the matching? Thank you.

Comment: Probably someone can help you. Details postponed.

Comment: Well... Help with what exactly? Your question is very broad and vague. Please, and I mean it in the most polite way, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: So, I'll try again. I explain all my problem I have a satellite image and a 3D data array of this satellite. My goal is to determine the pose. I have already studied the image, I have extrapolated the main features and the lines from the image. Now my problem is to see if there are some lines, characteristics in the 2D image that corresponds to my 3D model. If there is this correspondence between 2D lines and 3D lines, I can find the pose. So I do not know how to make this correspondence between 2D and 3D lines/points.

Comment: I known that I have to construct, so called, a "correspondence matrix" for the correspondence of the lines/points. This "matching matrix" is the necessary input for the EPnP solver. That is the question. How do you combine this? I hope it is clear. Thank you.